# ScrollView not taking up full width on iPhone 8, but it is on iPhone 8+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

[iPhone 8+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLxt4.jpg)

[iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDq6x.jpg)

The ScrollView is setup using AutoLayout so I'm not sure why it's taking up a smaller % of the width on the iPhone 8 vs the iPhone 8+. New to iOS development and this has been giving me a tough time. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the setup code for the ScrollView

```
let pageWidth: CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width
    let pageHeight: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.height

    do {
        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tutorial-data1", withExtension: "json") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            tutorialItems = try JSONDecoder().decode([TutorialItemData].self, from: data)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    pageControl.numberOfPages = tutorialItems.count
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pageWidth * CGFloat(tutorialItems.count), height: pageHeight)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstTutorialCompleted") == false {
        backButton.isHidden = true
    }

    for (index, item) in tutorialItems.enumerated() {
        if let tutorialView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TutorialItem", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? TutorialItemView {
            tutorialView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(index) * pageWidth, y: 0.0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
            print("frame pos: \(tutorialView.frame)")

            tutorialView.tutorialItemText.text = item.text
            tutorialView.tutorialItemImage.image = UIImage(named: item.image)
            scrollView.addSubview(tutorialView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are your `scrollView` AutoLayout constraints?

Comment: like [this](https://imgur.com/jRguo9D)